# Why should update be preferred over assoc?

Tags: functional-programming, clojure

In clojure, to edit the values of the keys of a map, there are 2 options available:

1. `update`
2. `assoc`

The only difference that I could find from the clojure documentation is that the `update` function does the following extra thing:

> If the key does not exist, nil is passed as the old value.

Are there any specific use cases where in I should use update or assoc other than this?

Or in which cases I should prefer what (If I have missed these use cases).

Answer (score 3):

They both state clear intent in your code when used properly:

- `assoc` hints to the reader, that *new* kv-pairs are added (or
  replacing the values for existing keys) and that they tend to not be
  relying on the current values for that keys.
- `update` hints, that one value for a key gets updated and the original
  value (if present) maybe used for this calculation.

```clj
(update {} :a (fnil inc 0))
; → {:a 1}
(update {:a 41} :a (fnil inc 0))
; → {:a 42}
(assoc {:z 0} :a 42 :b 23}
; → {:z 0, :a 42, :b 23}
```

Answer (score 2):

You an emulate `update` with `assoc` as follows

```
(assoc m :foo (f (:foo m)))
```

which looks clunky and is better off as:

```
(update m :foo f)
```

which returns a new map with `f` applied on the the value corresponding to the `:foo` key.

Comment: This is actually how `update` is implemented

Comment: Not only is this clunky, it works poorly for values of `m` which are expensive or side-effectful to compute. If you need to update a key's value and you care about the previous value, `update` is the way to go.

Comment: @amalloy Since `update` is implemented as `(defn update [m k f] (assoc m k (f (get m k))))`, why is it that OP's version *works poorly for values of m which are expensive or side-effectful to compute*? Is `get` better than using the keyword as a function?

Comment: @Thumbnail I'm talking about the difference between `(assoc (expensive-map) k (f (get (expensive-map) k)))` and `(update (expensive-map) k f)`. Because `update` is a function, it naturally gets its argument evaluated only once. But if you use `assoc`, you have to go even further out of your way to avoid double-evaluating the map.